# bcoin watch only address

Tags: watch-only, bcoin

Can anyone tell me how to set up a watch-only address using bcoin?

while using the command:

```
bcoin wallet create myNewWallet
```

this will always be a  `"watchOnly": false` wallet by default. Is there any documentation for these commands?

Answer (score 1):

The commands are listed on the [bcoin GitHub wiki](https://github.com/bcoin-org/bcoin/wiki/CLI)

The command you are looking for is
`bcoin wallet watch [address]`

Comment: This only returns me an Error which I couldn´t resolve till now: `Error: socket hang up
    at createHangUpError (_http_client.js:345:15)
    at Socket.socketOnEnd (_http_client.js:437:23)
    at emitNone (events.js:110:20)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:207:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1045:12)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:138:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)`

Comment: regarding the debug.log I can find the following extra information `AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: Network mismatch for address.` but the address is a vaild testnet address and the system is running on testnet too.

Comment: Are you starting your node with the option `--network=testnet` on (or alternatively you export the global `BCOIN_NETWORK='testnet'`) I tried with the above command and a testnet address and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to pass in the option `--watch` when creating the wallet or, in node, you can use `bcoin.http.Client.createWallet({ id: 'myNewWallet', watchOnly: true})`